# Cant open IIS7 Manager - invalid XML in applicationHost.config

Tags: iis, iis-7

Im a developer with very limited knowledge of IIS7 administration. Today when attempting to open the IIS instance via the IIS admin GUI i received a message that reads (paraphrased):

"There was an error trying to connect. Do you want to retype your credentials.
Error: applicationHost file is malformed xml" - Or similar.

Looking at applicationHost.config file I see that it is empty. Any ideas how I restore this file, or what I can add to it to restore it to its default state?

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is Windows Vista and have a recent backup of your whole machine, you could try to restore the file using the **Backup and Restore Center**.

The author of the following blog post had the same problem: [My Web Server's Dead - Corrupt applicationHost.config](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/08/26/10690.aspx)

---

If you just need a copy of the **content of that file** (for Windows Vista), I copied the XML text from a clean Vista installation and put a ZIP file you can download [**here**](http://www.mediafire.com/?sharekey=b7d4a13b3451498f6e7203eb87368129e04e75f6e8ebb871). I guess you'll have to stop the IIS service before you access the file.

Answer (score 1):

I found backups of my ApplicationHost.config at c:\Inetpub\History

Answer (score 0):

This Issue is due to file 'applicationhost.config' gets corrupt.

mostly backup of this file is stored @ C:\inetpub\history. Delete corrupted file C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config and restore it from backup. Then start \ restart IIS.

Problem will get solved.